# Iran's Military in Which Regime Had More Power?

Tags: military, iran

At the moment, Iran holds the 14th rank in military power in comparison to other countries. Iran's Supreme Leader claims that he has been prioritizing military power over the economy to increase stability. But in contrast, all the information tells us that Iran's military equipment after the revolution is outdated, and they only have manpower and missiles.

I want to know if Iran under the Islamic Republic regime is more successful in providing better military results in comparison to the Shah's regime.

Basically, I am asking for Iran's military power rank in 1978.

Comment: such rankings are somewhat subjective (involve weights etc.), and whatever source you found for that  (which you should probably make explicit to have any change of an answer) probably wasn't doing it 40+ years ago.

Comment: BTW, the title of the Q is a bit misleading. I first thought you were asking about political power. Undoubtedly, it has less power now (of that kind), but that also compromises its effectiveness because the regime has coup-proofed itself by creating parallel armies like the IRGC etc., which doesn't actually bode well in an actual high-intensity war, but works fine for guerilla actions both at home (if needed) and abroad.

Comment: FWIW, [Globalfirepower](https://www.globalfirepower.com/country-military-strength-detail.php?country_id=iran) seems a bit of a joke with its PwrIndx (TM) system.  Note Ukraine's position at #22 and Russia's at #2.  2 years ago, Saudi was ranked above Israel. They're catchy, cute, and IMHO, utterly meaningless for serious analysis.  FWIW, Iran's forces are probably about as good as they can be, sanctions considered.  I mean they *are* selling to Russia.  Whether or not that is useful to the average Iranian on the street and justifies the sanction and economic privations is totally another thing

Comment: Any way to compare the two things separated 44 years and an entirely different world scene would come down to a matter of opinion. There is no reasonable way to compare the two.

Comment: What are military results you are interested in? Against external enemies? Not easy to compare, during the Islamic regime there was a war with Iraq, but during the Shah's regime there were no comparable wars. In case you meant military results against the Iranian population the Islamic regime already lasted 44 years. The Shah depending if you count from the coronation date or the 1953 coup lasted 26 or 38 years.

Comment: There is no link to the study that ranked Iran in the 14th position, what parameters is it based on? Military spending? Number of active soldiers? Most of the commonly used parameters actually do not give a measure of the real military power.

Comment: @Fluidcode  It's very likely the globalfirepower.com folk's "study".  See link on my comment.  Their methodology is to "count the shinies".  That's how [North Korea ends up #3 in world tank strength](https://www.globalfirepower.com/armor-tanks-total.php) .  Another measure of their expertise, from their site: *Try the coalitions builder: Two coalitions, up to seven nations each - who would win?*

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: ironically they put NK at #30 overall and SK at #6, despite the fact that the former can nuke the latter in a one-on-one. Likewise Pakistan and the UK are declared near equals (#8 and #9). Does anyone seriously believe that (yea, Pakistan has nukes too, but probably none can reach the UK--does anyone think their T-72 army is a match for Challengers), etc.

Comment: @Fizz Every time that sorry website gets mentioned here, it should be re-clarified how irrelevant it is to actual military affairs.  It might be an OK gaming or special interest website, but that's about it and that is **not** how it presents itself.  Iran's armed forces may however rank considerably higher than #14 worldwide when it comes to population repression capability ratings...

Comment: That's not a fair comparison. For example look at the number of people in the military service. It's obvious that with time and population growth that number also grows. So comparing today and past in this aspect makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in contrast all the informtation tells that Iran's military equipment after revolution are too old and far behind the time and It's only have manpower and missiles.

Mostly true.

Iran's air force and navy lack funding and advanced technology. That is the effect of US sanctions. As a result, Iran's military can only function as a defensive force.

.

> I want to know, If Iran under Islamic Republic regime is successful to provider better military results in comparison to Shah's regime.

It depends on what kind of conflict you are talking about.

Shah's military was well-funded and had the most advanced weapons at that time. However, it had no morale and was only to show off, just like Saudi Arabia. Therefore, it was never meant to win a war.

> <sub>*The armed forces still remained a rapid and sure path to a higher social status. As such, they attracted the less powerful and the less affluent who needed the social and financial security the military provided. But, the attractions provided by careers in the civilian sector, continuously eroded the appeal of the military, particularly in the 1970s. The low pay scale for those below the rank of colonel and strict discipline further reduced the appeal of the military as a career. As early as the 1960s, it was mostly the lower middle strata of the population who enlisted as officer cadets (L. Hamon, Le rôle extra-militaire de l’armée dans le tiers monde, Paris, 1966, p. 193). In the 1970s the social gap between the military and the ruling class became much more serious. A source in the U.S. military attaché indicated in 1974 that the sons of prominent families had come to shun the military service (E. R. Oney, Elites and the Distribution of Power in Iran, Central Intelligence Agency, Secret, February, 1976, pp. 48, 51, repr. by Dānešǰūyān-e Mosalmān-e Payrow-e Ḵaṭṭ-e Emām, Asnād-e lāna-ye ǰāsūsī VII, Tehran, 1981). While the high ranking officers were gradually integrated in the ruling class, the bulk of the officers’ corps were not. The conscripts, in particular, performed menial tasks and received meager compensations. Consequently, the loyalty of the military to the regime in the long run was questionable, and this may partially explain the shah’s reluctance to unleash the military during the civil unrests of 1978-79.*</sub>

Present-day Iran has enough capability to defend itself from a foreign invasion from NATO even though it is poorly funded.

.

> Simply if we could know the Iran's military power rank in 1978 would be enough.

I think this information is not available. It's possible no one ranked military power as they do nowadays.

.

**Reference**

- [ARMY vi. Pahlavi Period](https://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/army-vi)

Comment: Not sure how informative it is, but [this exercise in 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Challenge_2002) ruffled US military feathers when it happened.  Seemed more Iran-simulating than Iraq.